# scilab 6.0.1 can't work sound command on my OSX 10.13.2

Tags: macos, scilab

these are Scilab's console.

```
--> t=(1:8000)/8000;

--> x=0.3*sin(2*%pi*1000*t);

--> sound(x,8000);
at line    47 of function playsnd ( /Applications/scilab-6.0.1.app/Contents/MacOS/share/scilab/modules/sound/macros/playsnd.sci line 61 )
at line    33 of function sound   ( /Applications/scilab-6.0.1.app/Contents/MacOS/share/scilab/modules/sound/macros/sound.sci line 46 )

playsnd: Failed to play the sound with command: aplay  /var/folders/15/717pz4vd6sn65dz7g05lgl180000gn/T//SCI_TMP_62898_iN7qqV/_playsnd_.wav > /dev/null 2>&1.
```

What shoud I do?

Answer (score 1):

This bug has been fixed in Scilab 6.0.2 (see https://codereview.scilab.org/#/c/20756/).